# Who was in charge of the Barysaw massacre (20 October 1941)?

Tags: world-war-two, 20th-century, nazi-germany, soviet-union, russia

I'm looking for information about the Barysaw Massacre of 20 October 1941.
Who performed it and who was in charge of this operation?

Comment: Upon researching this, Immediately stumbled over two [Khatyn Massacres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatyn_massacre) in 1940 and 1943. Khatyn is about 40KM from Barysaw. What a horrible time in history that was.

Comment: a time of exceptional cruelty, no doubt, but not much more different then today Im afraid...the two events you described have no relation to the Barysaw events.

Comment: @T.E.D. The 1940 Katyn massacre is not the same place as the 1943 Khatyn massacre.

Comment: @T.E.D. seems you are confusing two places.

Comment: The action that day, as far as I know at least took action against Jews only, but that's about all that I know...

Comment: I see no record of such a massacre; is it possible that you refer to the Borisov massacre?

Comment: Considering that Anixx found the answer in wikipedia, I'm surprised this question didn't get closed as trivial. (Please note, I'm not suggesting the _event_ was trivial, it was not, but that the answer was trivial to look up.) The accepted answer is, in fact, duplicating wiki...

Comment: It may be so if you're fluent in Russian and know where to look, otherwise finding sources and info is a bit challenging is it not @CGCampbell ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On October, 20-21 1941, the German occupation authority of Borisov (headed by Stanislav Stankevich with the participation of [Obersturmführer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obersturmf%C3%BChrer) Kraffe) performed liquidation of the Jewish ghetto. At the day were killed 7 245 Jews. The upcoming action was announced on a banquet by the city administration.

The performers were mostly Russian auxiliary police headed by a Volga German David Egof. Other involved forces were the units of Wehrmacht as well as a Latvian SD company under command of Obersturmführer Kraffe who arrived from Minsk for the event.

According the Egof's words, the next day they also killed about 1000 people in the course of cleaning up the ghetto's territory.

In 1943 Germans ordered Russian POWs to open the ditch and burn the bodies of the victims so to cover up the massacre. All the POWs who participated were executed afterwards.

Before the war Egof was a teacher of German language near Borisov, who was elevated by the German administration due to his German ancestry. He was tried in 1947 and got 25 years in prison, because death penalty was abolished in the USSR at the time. After he served the term he was released.

[image]

Before the occupation started Jews constituted 20% of the city's population, that is 10000 people of 49000 total.

Comment: not bad..where did you find the source?

Comment: @Bak1139 from Russian Wikipedia: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: Any knowledge about the eventual whereabouts and faith of obersturmbannführer Kraft, obersturmbannführer Kaffe and Egof?

Comment: @Bak1139 I only found information about David Davidovich Egof. Before the war he was a teacher of German language near Borisov. He was tried after the war and got 25 years in prison, after the term he was released. http://rpp.nm.ru/teacher/teacher.html

Comment: Thank you, this was the most extensive resource I found so far about this matter...It's a shame that the whereabouts of the two SS man couldn't be verified...as far as I could understand, there were other actions against Jews before 20 of October in Borisov?

Comment: @Bak1139 Jews were re-settled to the ghetto and non-Jews were prohibited to speak with them. Upon spotting a Jew on a street, the non-Jews were required to switch the street side, any greetings were prohibited as well, including nodding the head or raising the hat from the distance. Upon installing their regime, the Germans made teacher Egof a burgomаster of the town Zembin because of his German origin. At 18 August all Jews in Zembin (760 to 900) were totally killed, with assistance of Egof.

Comment: @Bak1139 In September 1941 he also participated in killing of about 1000 Jews in Begoml. He also participated in killing about 600 Jews in Obchuga in autumn, 1941.

Comment: @Bak1139 seems there was only one obersturmfurer Kraffe, and the other name is a typo. He was an SD officer arrived from Minsk for the massacre.

Comment: that's very detailed...but I meant killing actions in Borisov before October 20th..?

Comment: @Bak1139 Wikipedia lists only separated cases of killing in Borisov before October, it names 8 people killed upon occupation started, according the witnesses.

Comment: no mass murders at all? 1500 died before the operation of October 20th...because it says there were 9000 victims at total...

Comment: @Bak1139 Egof says they killed 1000 people the next day. This may be included.

Comment: Also, our Nazi guy: http://forum.axishistory.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=143633

Comment: Did they find the mass grave?